# Optimize PHP Mysql Count Function

Tags: php, mysql, count

I count MySQL rows using this function:

```
function sqlcount($table)
{
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(0) FROM $table;");
     $sql = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
     return $sql[0];     
}
```

Print the result:

```
echo sqlcount("members");
```

But this does not work and does not show the true count. What is the problem?

Comment: You Should Probably Not Type With Every Letter In Upper Case Because It's Hard To Read, Also `COUNT(0)` Makes No Sense, Use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Why do you think it does not work? What does it print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this also :

```
function sqlcount($table)
{
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $table;");
     $sql = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
     return $sql['num'];     
}
```

or instead of `COUNT(*)` set any field name of the selected Database.

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(0)`

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table;");
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function sqlcount($table)
{
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM ".     mysql_real_escape_string($table) .";");
     $sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
     return $sql['count'];     
}
```